# what's The difference between syncfusion buttons and winForm buttons

Tags: c#, button, syncfusion

i'am trying to convert selected rows of datagridview to a data table.
when i test this code on winForm button it work properly and return all of selected rows,
but the syncfusion button return selectedrows-1 rows of datagridview items.
what's The difference between syncfusion buttons and winForm buttons and what's the solution to this problem ?

my code :

```
    try
    {
        DataTable TempDtTable = (dgv_Cert.DataSource as DataTable).AsEnumerable().Where(  
            p => !p.Field<string>("tier_name").Equals("value1") && p.Field<bool?>(CheckColumn) == true).CopyToDataTable();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("xxx");
    }
```

Comment: _when I test this code on WinForm button..._ Oh well where is the code?

Comment: I remember at my last job we had to use SyncFusion's stuff. Biggest waste of time in my developper's life.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion's ButtonAdv is just a button control capable of displaying  images with different alignments and various border styles, also it supports some additional feature to the standard Windows Forms Button.

But regarding the functionality there is no difference between Winform button control and Syncfusion's button control. Hope you have used the codes within the click action of button, both the controls triggers the events which related to clicking in the following order.

Mouse Down,
Click,
Mouse Click,
Mouse Up.

So it may be any other reason for the reported behavior.